# Gitolite usernames in authorized_keys file

Tags: git, gitolite, authorized-keys

I'll try to explain my scenario the best I can:

I'm using gitolite in a debian squeeze server and there are 3 users who can access and work with the repositories:

- `alex@workbox`
- `alex@homebox`
- `katy@workbox`

The above are the corresponding usernames and hostnames of three Ubuntu boxes (Alex works from two locations).

The first thing I did was to add `alex@workbox` to the gitolite:

1. Alex generated his ssh key using ssh-keygen
2. I copied his ssh key as alex@workbox.pub in "keydir" folder of my local gitolite-admin cloned repo
3. Modified conf/gitolite.conf file of my local gitolite-admin cloned repo in order to let alex@workbox RW access to a repository:
   `repo    project1`
   `RW+     =   alex@workbox`
4. Did the usual:

   - `git add .`
   - `git commit -m "Added alex@workbox"`
   - `git push`

When Alex tried to clone the project1 repo an error showed up saying that access for user "`alex`" was denied.
So, I logged in into the server and opened `/var/lib/gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
The first part of the file was this:

```
command="/usr/share/gitolite/gl-auth-command alex",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa...
```

So I manually replaced `alex` with `alex@workbox`, saved the file and this time Alex was able to clone the repository and work with it without any problems.

Then I did the same above steps to add Katy and after the push to `gitolite-admin`, I opened again the `authorized_keys` file and saw that gitolite replaced the "`user@hostname`" with "`user`".
So it had `alex` instead of `alex@workbox` and the same for `katy`.
Then I had to manually replace that again and save the file.
I saw that for every push that I do for the `gitolite-admin` repo gitolite replaces every "`user@hostname`" with "`user`" in its `.ssh/authorized_keys` and this way make the repositories inaccessible for the users.

How can I do to make gitolite keep the "`user@hostname`"?
Is there a configuration to make on the server or a configuration change on my local cloned `gitolite-admin` repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[configuration syntax](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/syntax.html)** mentions:

> User names and repo names are as simple as possible; they must start with an alphanumeric, but after that they can also contain `.`, `_`, or `-`.
>
> Usernames can optionally be **followed by an `@` and a `domainname` containing at least one `.`** (this allows you to use an email address as someone's username).

Your naming convention doesn't follow the proper syntax for having an '`@`'.

You can see this rule in action in [`src/triggers/post-compile/ssh-authkeys`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/triggers/post-compile/ssh-authkeys#L131-L145)

```
sub optionise {
    my $f = shift;

    my $user = $f;
    $user =~ s(.*/)(); # foo/bar/baz.pub -> baz.pub
    $user =~ s/(\@[^.]+)?\.pub$//; # baz.pub, baz@home.pub -> baz

    my @line = slurp($f);
    if ( @line != 1 ) {
        _warn "$f does not contain exactly 1 line; ignoring";
        return '';
    }
    chomp(@line);
    return "command=\"$glshell $user" . ( $kfn ? " $f" : "" ) . "\",$auth_options $line[0]";
}
```

Comment: Thanks VonC for your answer. Really appreciate it. So I will try to have usernames like alex@workbox.local. I will make the corresponding changes on the boxes, ssh keys and gitolite-admin to see how it goes.

Comment: Worked great. Edited gitolite-admin/conf/gitolite.conf and replaced alex@workbox with alex.workbox. Then renamed gitolite-admin/keydir/alex@workbox.pub to alex.workbox.pub and the correct entry was updated in server's /var/lib/gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys. Alex can now work without problems. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You should really never need to directly modify the Gitolite section of the `authorized_keys` file.

The idea of the `@suffix` addition to keyfile pathnames is that it allows the administrator to easily add multiple keys for a single Gitolite user. In your case, `keydir/alex@workbox.pub` and `keydir/alex@homebox.pub` are both mapped to a single Gitolite user named `alex`. This is usually what you want if both of those keys are “owned” by the same person; it lets you just use `alex` in the configuration file instead of having to mention both keyfile names. If those keys are owned by different people (or you want to enforce different access restrictions for a person’s different keys), then you will need to name them slightly differently (either use a separator other than `@`, or include at least one period between the `@` and `.pub`).

## Multiple Keys per User

The Gitolite documentation section named [“multiple keys per user”](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/users.html#multi-key) describes the ways you can configure multiple keys for a single Gitolite user. There are two main ways:

- put files named `username.pub` in different subdirectories of `keydir` (the newer method),
- put an `@` suffix after the username (the older method, which has sometimes been difficult for Gitolite admins to grok).

With the subdirectory method, you would use pathnames like these:

```
keydir/workbox/alex.pub
keydir/homebox/alex.pub
```

With the suffix method, you would use pathnames like these:

```
keydir/alex@workbox.pub
keydir/alex@homebox.pub
```

All of the above pathnames supply keys that will authenticate as the Gitolite user named `alex` (no `@` in the user’s name); you would use (e.g.) `RW+ = alex` in the configuration file. These methods (only using a portion of the key’s pathname to form the Gitolite username) let the admin add (and remove) keys for Gitolite users without having to edit the configuration file every time someone wants to use a new key (or loses access to (or control of) an old key).

For example, if `alex` gets a new mobile device, you could add `keydir/mobile/alex.pub` or `keydir/alex@mobile.pub` to give that key access to everything that `alex` can already access.

### Email-style Usernames

There is a limitation to the suffix method: the suffix must *not* contain a period. This limitation exists so that you can use email addresses as usernames; you can still use suffixes (or subdirectories) with such usernames. The following key pathnames could be used to supply keys for the username `jane@gmail.com` (`@gmail.com` is a part of username):

```
keydir/external/jane@gmail.com.pub
keydir/jane@gmail.com@remotebox.pub
```

This `jane@gmail.com` user is distinct from a plain `jane` user.

Note: By manually adding an `@workbox` suffix to the `authorized_keys` entry, you effectively forced Gitolite to use an email-type username that contained no period (based on how the keydir pathnames are parsed into usernames, this is normally impossible).

### Which to Use?

It seems like subdirectories make the most sense when you expect to be able to fit your users’ keys into a limited number of categories (home, work, mobile, etc.). The `@`-suffixes seem useful if you have one-off keys that do not fit in any particular category.

Independent of subdirectory/suffix, email-style usernames might be useful for anyone that does not otherwise have a canonical username inside your organization (e.g. a temporary outside contractor).

## Summary

Gitolite usernames are derived from the pathnames under `keydir`, but the are not identical to the filenames used there. Specifically, the `keydir` pathnames are mapped to usernames by stripping any subdirectories and removing the `.pub` extension along with any `@` suffixes (as long as there is no period after the `@`—otherwise the `@` is treated as part of an email-style username).

If you have a situation where a single person wants to use multiple keys, then you should probably use one of the above methods (subdirectories, or `@` suffix (without a period)) to let you map multiple keys to a single Gitolite username.

Example: install `keydir/workbox/alex.pub` and `keydir/homebox/alex.pub`, then use `alex` in the configuration file (giving equal access to both keys).

If you have keys for different people that you want to give similar names, or you want to authorize different access for a single person’s various keys (home access is read only?), then you should use a separator other than `@` between the distinguishing parts of the username (or make sure there is a period after the `@` so it is treated as an email-style username).

Example: install `keydir/workbox/alex.pub`, `keydir/homebox/alex-ro.pub`, and `mobile/alex-ro.pub`, then use `alex` and `alex-ro` in the configuration file (e.g. in some way that gives `alex-ro` read-only access, while `alex` gets read-write access).

Comment: Nice addition to my answer. +1